# Does fixing partial bits of a SHA256 hash increase the probability of finding a preimage using the meet-in-the-middle attack?

Tags: hash, sha-256, meet-in-the-middle-attack

Let’s say I want to find a partial rather than full preimage using the meet-in-the-middle attack. For example, my goal is to find a preimage so that the first 76-bit output of the hash are all consisted of the number 1.

Does finding a partial preimage have a better chance of success than finding a full preimage using the meet-in-the-middle attack? If so, what is the complexity of this attack?

EDIT: I know that there is no full-round meet-in-the-middle attack against SHA256 to find full preimages. However, my question is: would it be easier to execute a full-round meet-in-the-middle attack to find a partial preimage instead?

Comment: Note that there is no full round meet-in-the-middle attack on SHA256.

Comment: @kelalaka I know that there is no full round meet-in-the-middle attack against SHA256 to find a full preimage. However, would it be easier to accomplish a full round meet-in-the-middle attack to find a partial preimage instead?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the researchers would go in this way if they saw that there is a better result than the existing one.